# Java / my classes are not seeing each other?

Tags: java

I have two classes:

**Model/User.java**

```
package Model;

public class User {
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    User( int id, String firstName, String lastName )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and

**Repositories/UserRespository.java**

```
package Repositories;
import Model.User;

public class UserRepository 
{
    public User CreateUser( int id, String firstName, String lastName )
    {
        User newUser = new User( id, firstName, lastName );
        return newUser;
    }

    public User GetUserById()
    {
        User user = new User( id, firstName, lastName );
        return user;
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
firstName cannot be resolved    MVCExample/src/Repositories UserRepository.java line 14 1372765344696   53

id cannot be resolved   MVCExample/src/Repositories UserRepository.java line 14 1372765344695   52

lastName cannot be resolved MVCExample/src/Repositories UserRepository.java line 14 1372765344696   54

The constructor User(int, String, String) is not visible    MVCExample/src/Repositories UserRepository.java line 8  1372765344695   51
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `GetUserById` is a problem. You need to pass the values in order to pass it to the `User` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the constructor of class `User` as `public`.

Answer (score 1):

```
User user = new User( id, firstName, lastName );
```

You are using this  without declaring `id`, `firstName` and `lastName`

Answer (score 0):

in this part of your code:

```
public User GetUserById()
{
    User user = new User( id, firstName, lastName );
    return user;
}
```

you are not declaring id, firstName and lastName, you need to declare them as instance variables if you want them to be available, also, in this part:

```
User( int id, String firstName, String lastName )
{
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

you need to declare your constructor **public**.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to

```
 public User GetUserById(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        User user = new User( id, firstName, lastName );
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your User class constructor as public, like:

```
public User( int id, String firstName, String lastName )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```